# Xamarin XLabs IOC and camera

Tags: xamarin

I'm looking at https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/Samples/XLabs.Sample/ViewModel/CameraViewModel.cs to try and get the camera available to my app.

I have this setup the same, but when I run my app the iOS app that calls my PCL is giving the error:

```
IResolver has not been set. Please set it by calling Resolver.SetResolver(resolver) method.
```

I don't know what this means or what exact code I need. I don't use IOC at all and I don't much care about it but I just want this camera to be available to my PCL. How can I get this camera available to my PCL when I'm not using MVC here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to use the ViewModel then modify the constructor to take in  IMediaPicker:

https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/Samples/XLabs.Sample/ViewModel/CameraViewModel.cs#L62

```
    public CameraViewModel(IMediaPicker mediaPicker)
    {
        this._mediaPicker = mediaPicker;
    }
```

Remove the Setup function:

https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/Samples/XLabs.Sample/ViewModel/CameraViewModel.cs#L156-L167

How you get the IMediaPicker implementation to PCL is up to you. IoC is the preferred (and easy) way but you can use other patterns as well. One would be to define a static `Func<IMediaPicker>` property on the ViewModel and set it in the platform specific projects.

IoC container is the easiest and quickest way to get it done and it would as simple as adding these lines at the application startup (e.g. AppDelegate's FinishedLaunching method):

```
var container = new SimpleContainer();
container.Register<IMediaPicker, MediaPicker>();
Resolver.SetResolver(container.GetResolver());
```

Comment: That's the question I'm really asking. I don't know how to get the IMediaPicker implementation using XLabs. I'm not picky about how I get it I just need to know how to get it as I don't know how to do that.

Comment: So XLabs examples use DependencyService. When you read about DependencyService it says at the top of each platform specific implementation to add an assembly attribute so that it's automatically registered. http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/

This doesn't seem to be the case with XLabs though as when you look at their implementation they aren't doing that. So I'm not sure how to manually register the MediaPicker for IoC

Comment: I updated my answer for a sample on how to setup the Resolver with IMediaPicker. If you are using Xamarin Forms then you could use DependencyService to register and resolve but that would require changes to the ViewModel itself.